# How can I make the last line print both first key in the first dictonary and the second value of the second dictonary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

```
name_info = {
    'Mej': 'L.',
    'Loa': 'J.',
    'Jakob': 'B.',
    'Albert': 'A.',
    'Jessica': 'J.',
    'Matilda': 'Z.',
    } 
    username_info = {
    name_info['Mej'] + "Username: Demonkiller99",
    name_info['Loa'] + "Username: Meklah" } 
    for first_name in name_info.keys():
    print(first_name + username_info)
```

**How can I make it so the code, prints the first key from the 1 dictionary + the username info from the second?**

Comment: that second data structure is not a dictionary, it is a set

Comment: Ok. What should I do then? put {} for each name so I get dictionaries in a dictionary?

Comment: you should create a dictionary not a set probably but also why do you have two dictionaries? just put all info of a user in one dictionary